What to do if notification does show when app is in foreground, also it does not have type or data but it has title and body?
I am trying to show a notification, when app is in the background or killed the notification shows. It's handled by system. But when app is in the foreground the notification does not show. Its data and type are null but it has title and body. Is it okay to try to show them even though the remoteMessage.data["data"] is null and also remoteMessage.data["type"] is null but the message payload its not null?
Is it okay to try to show the notifications even though that type and data are null, we only have title and body, or what to do in this case?
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
        val notificationId = Random().nextInt(60000)
        val messageData = remoteMessage.data["data"]
        val messageDataString = remoteMessage.data["data"].toString()
        val messageType = remoteMessage.data["type"]

        //notification title and body are not null 
        val notificationTitle = remoteMessage.data["title"] ?: remoteMessage.notification?.title
        val notificationBody = remoteMessage.data["body"] ?: remoteMessage.notification?.body
        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val channelId = getString(R.string.message_notification_channel_id)
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name = App.instance.applicationContext.getString(R.string.message_notification_channel_name)
            val descriptionText = App.instance.applicationContext.getString(R.string.message_notification_channel_name)
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance).apply {
                description = descriptionText
                enableLights(true)
                enableVibration(true)

                if (defaultSoundUri != null) {
                    val att = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                            .build()
                    setSound(defaultSoundUri, att)
                }
                lightColor = Color.parseColor("#501450")
            }
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        if (!messageType.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            if(AppPreferences.userNotifications){
                val intent = Intent(this, StartActivity::class.java)
//            intent.putExtra(AStrings.PUSH_TYPE, messageType)
//            intent.putExtra(AStrings.PUSH_DATA, messageData)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
                intent.action = "actionString" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                val pendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

                val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)//a resource for your custom small icon
                    .setColor(Color.parseColor("#222831"))
                    .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.notification!!.title)//the "title" value you sent in your notification
                    .setContentText(remoteMessage.notification!!.body) //ditto
                    .setAutoCancel(true) //dismisses the notification on click
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setVibrate(LongArray(0))
                    .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)   // heads-up
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

                notificationManager.notify(
                    notificationId /* ID of notification */,
                    notificationBuilder.build()
                )
            } else {
                notificationManager.cancelAll()
            }
        }
    }

